# Preserve reference to element after deletion and subsequent re-insertion

Tags: jquery

Within document.ready, I store a selector in a variable (which I assume once evaluated, stores the element object in said variable), as I need to manipulate it many times.

ie. `myVar = $('#mySpan');`

What I'm storing is a span element within a div. One of the manipulations requires me to overwrite the contents of the div using the .html() function.

After, I need to reinsert that span element inside the div mentioned above and do so using the html() function.

The problem I have is that once the span element has been re-added, the variable myVar is no longer associated with the span element. I assume this is because it was deleted from the DOM and then re-added.

I know that jquery has the .detach() function, but that seems to only preserve attached events and data elements, but not actual references. I don't even thing the .live() function would help in this case either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

If you want to preserve the content in a variable for later insertion, just simply store it in a variable using `.contents()`, then reinsert it when needed.

jQuery's `.contents()` method selects all content, including text nodes.

- http://api.jquery.com/contents/

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/bD2Ej/2/ *(click the text to toggle)*

This example toggles between the original and new content.

```
var myVar;

// Add the new content, and append the element stored in myVar
$('#somediv').toggle(function() {
    myVar = $(this).contents();
    $(this).html('some new content<br>');
}, function() {
    $(this).html( myVar );
});
​
```

---

**Original ansewr:**

If you used `.detach()` you would still need to store it in a variable.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bD2Ej/

```
   // Detach and reference the element in a variable
myVar = $('#mySpan').detach();

   // Add the new content, and append the element stored in myVar
$('#somediv').html('somecontent').append( myVar );
```

But are you sure you need `.html()`? Could you just use `.append()` so the `#mySpan` isn't overwritten in the first place?

Comment: What happens if the span element has to be reinserted between some plain text? 

That's why I used .html()

Comment: @genbayer - I would need to see your specific situation. Is the plain text part of the new `.html()` content? Or was it existing, and also needs to be preserved?

Comment: Basically, this is what I need to do

Original content:
[div]original content text [span] and some more text[/div]

Then, I need to overwrite the content in the div above:
[div]new content[/div]

Finally, I need to replace the content in the div with what was there originally. So, once again:
[div]original content text [span] and some more text[/div]

Comment: @genbayer - If you're saying that you need to replace it *at a later time*, then just store it all in a variable, and add it later. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Try clone();

```
myVar = $('#mySpan').clone();
$('#mySpan').remove();
$('#somediv').html(myVar);
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/